# HTML.BeginForm sends Post always to index action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sitefinity, html.beginform

I'm trying to post a form through html beginForm but the method called is always [httpPost] index instead of the method specified in the post (Search).

What could I be doing wrong?

Here's  my form:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "MyController", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <p>
            Postal Code: @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PostalCode) <br />
            City: @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PostalCodeCity ) <br />
            Address: @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Address) <br />
            <input type="submit" value="submit" />
        </p>
    }
```

My model:

```
public class MyModel
    {

        public string PostalCode { get; set; }

        public string PostalCodeCity { get; set; }

        public string Address { get; set; }

}
```

My Routes:

```
 routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.Ignore("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");


            //Routing for ASP.NET MVC Controllers

            routes.MapRoute(
            name: "ControllersRoute",
            url: "mvc/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = UrlParameter.Optional });


            //Routing for Web Api Controller
            routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

My controller methods

```
public class MyController : Controller
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the message.
        /// </summary>
        [Category("String Properties")]
        public string Message { get; set; }


        /// <summary>
        /// This is the default Action.
        /// </summary>
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            MyModel model = new MyModel();

            return View("Default", model);
        }


        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(MyModel model)
        {


            //Refresh model attending session variables


            return View("Default", model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Search(MyModel model)
        {

                //model work

            return View("Default", model);
        }

    }
```

**UPDATE**

@markpsmith recommended me to check the form action and it was wrong.
it was action="order-calendar" than I Change it to action="order-calendar/search" and the action Search was called.

Is this a Route Problem?

Comment: Have you debugged the code to confirm that it's not hitting `Search`?

Comment: yes I've done it :/  I'm not undesrtanding what could be wrong

Comment: Can you check the generated HTML to confirm that the form action is `Search`?

Comment: probably has something to do with the fact it's a WebApi app. do you need a default route?

Comment: Its strange this is my form <form method="post" action="order-calendar" id="aspnetForm">

Comment: @JamieD77 Hello Jamie yes I need defaultApi Route because of WebApi Controllers

Comment: @markpsmith order-calendar its the name of the page

Comment: In chrome I changed the action to order-calendar/Search and it worked. But I dont know what is causing the action to be order-calendar. any thoughts?

Comment: Your controller is named `MyController`, therefore it needs to be `@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "My", FormMethod.Post))` (the second parameter is `"My"`,not `"MyController"`) - but other comments suggest you have more problems than just this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you have tagged Sitefinity, If so you should be try:

@using Telerik.Sitefinity.UI.MVC;
@using Telerik.Sitefinity.Frontend.Mvc.Helpers

@using(Html.BeginFormSitefinity()){}

Comment: Thank you sir! Thanks Correct! I have another problem right now and i'll post it in another thread. basically the form disappears after clicking.

Comment: Are you returning a view on your post action?

Comment: Hello, I'm Returning a RedirectToAction(); but the element disappears imeadiatly acter clicking. the removal is in the client side. and only later the postback is done. quite strange behavior.

Comment: Hard to say what's happening without seeing that part of your code. Wouldn't you want to return a view and show that the post was successful or not?

Comment: I've just posted the doubt in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32370564/beginformsitefinity-form-disappears-after-submiting let me know what you think :)

Answer (score 0):

The BeginForm helper use the routing engine to reach the "search" action of your controller. That helper use a method named GetVirtualPath() in the RouteTable class (something like **RouteTable.Route.GetVirtualPath()**).
If you are using the same page for the post action you can simply use the

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
```

without any param. Can you reach the "search" action using an URL compatible to your routing settings?

Comment: Hello theLaw I'll try that, but what do you mean with  "can you reach search action using an URL compatible to your routing settings?"?.

To reach Search from javascript for instance I use URL.RouteURL and not URL.Action because the second one returns a bad route. thats your question?

Comment: Try with your browser to go to mvc/MyController/Search

Comment: I'm getting a "The resource cannot be found.". but if i go to mvc/MyController/Index it is ok.

Comment: Try to use @using (Html.BeginForm(ViewContext.RouteData.Values.GetRequiredString("Search"), ViewContext.RouteData.Values.GetRequiredString("mycontroller"))))

Comment: And strongly type the model in the view like this @model YOURPATH.MyModel

Comment: theLaw the view already is strongly typed, about the ViewContext.RouteData.Values.GetRequiresString("action") looks good but the the GetRequiredString its not recognized? ('System.Web.Routing.RouteValuedictionary' does not contain a definition for GetRequiredString and no extension method Get RequiredString acceptiong a first argument of type 'System.Web.Routing.RouteValuedictionary' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) ) only ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiresString. But the previous method crushes my widget and I can't see its value.

Comment: What is the GetRequiredString namespace? maybe its a conflict